# Find the domain of the given function

Tags: vectors

Currently I am doing vector calculus and in one of the practice problems, it says:

Find the domain of the given function:

$$f(x,y)=y^2*e^{-x^2/2}$$

So for the Domain of this function, we should look at all the x-values which are possible.

Thus $Domain: x\in\Bbb R$

So the steps for this is just looking at the domain in the expression of $e^{-x^2/2}$ right?

So if this is the case, how do we do something for:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x+2y)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x^2+y^1-1}$$

Do we look at both the case $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ ?

Then would the domain be $Domain: x\in\Bbb Z$ because of the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ term?

Comment: Ah, but the domain of your first function should be two-dimensional, because there are two variables $x$ and $y$. So the domain should be a subset of the plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. But after that would the first one be right?

Comment: It depends. Which subset of the plane do you get as the domain for the first one? You also need to think in a similar way for the second one - which points $(x,y)$ can you plug into the function.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow what you mean by "which subset of the plane do you get as the domain for the first one?"

Comment: @HowDoIMath I think there's no second case. The second function is the OP trying to explain his rationale with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find function domain you should take the largest possible set and then reduce it if needed.
So here $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ but denominator should be non-zero, so $x^2 + y \neq 1$, or $y \neq 1-x^2$. Thus, the domain is formed by the following rule: $D(f) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y \neq 1-x^2\}$

Comment: That helps alot, and makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Wait why is the domain written with respect to (x,y)? not just x ? Isn't domain just x-values?

Comment: Math does not distinguish variable names. You may have $f = f(a,z)$ or any other set of variables. Domain is not a set of possible values of some argument (like $x$ or some other) but a set of all values of a vector containing arguments as coordinates. Here you have function depending on two variables, so the argument is $2$-dimensional vector, so the domain is a subset of two-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!